# RTOS: windows ce : Real mode and protected mode memory accessibility overhead

Tags: c++, windows-ce

I have a control loop between hardware and software using RTOS: windows ce.

I read data in from a device through Real mode.
I process the data in protected mode, due to limited memory in Real mode.
I then switch back to real mode to set another device based on results.

There is a lot of overhead in this and it slows things down.
Is there a way to access the same memory on the heap?  Is there a means of making this efficient so the overhead is at a minimum?

thanks

Comment: can't you use 'standard' shared memory (CreateFileMapping etc)?

Comment: Windows CE is an RTOS?  Coulda fooled me...

Comment: @John Dibling - yes WinCE is an RTOS, that's why it is used in automotive industry for example BMW, Fiat uses it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `VirtualCopy` API to map physical addresses into a process's virtual address space. There should be no need to drop down to real mode.

Comment: In fact I'd argue there is no "Real" mode in CE.  There's user and kernel.

Comment: I was assuming that this system uses an x86 processor, in which case, there is a real mode. Dropping out of protected mode is not actually supported in CE as far as I know, but if you're running in privileged space I suppose you can do that. The steps at http://wiki.osdev.org/Real_Mode#Switching_from_Protected_Mode_to_Real_Mode indicate why it might be a little slow... I'd definitely say that pulling the rug out from underneath your operating system is a Bad Idea.